# Cypher query crashes for small/medium dataset

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have imported 100K nodes into Neo4J and now I want to retrieve name values of these nodes.

My nodes has 2 properties (`id` and `name`) and 1 label (`User`).
I created index on nodes with `User` label and `name` property.

```
:schema
Indexes
  ON :User(name) ONLINE  

No constraints
```

I ran this cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n.name
LIMIT 1000
```

and it returned the result in few milliseconds.

Then I tried to retrieve 30000 nodes, changing the limit:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n.name
LIMIT 30000
```

and everytime I try to execute this query the page crashes. I tried to inspect memory usage every 5 seconds with free -m. Result is in the image below.

[image]

I'm working on a mediocre machine with 4GB of RAM, Ubuntu 14 and i5 CPU but asking for 30000 nodes doesn't seem a big request to me.

Maybe I'm tuning my machine in the wrong way.

In my  neo4j-wrapper.conf file I have:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=2048
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=2048
```

While in my neo4j.conf:

```
#dbms.memory.pagecache.size=2g
```

Comment: You're swapping, because 4 GB is not that large for the OS + Neo4j + browser. Are you trying to _display_ 30K rows in the browser? Whatever is hitting the swap will slow down to a crawl...

Comment: yes, I was trying to show all 30000 rows in the browser. What can I do (apart installing more ram)? Is neo4j tuning worthless in this case?

Comment: This is an issue with the web interface, it's just not designed to *display* large amounts of data. Try getting the data with a program/script.

Comment: You could decrease the heap (like 512) and set a smaller page cache explicitly, because it doesn't need that much memory for 100K nodes, which would leave more memory to the browser. But really, as Martin said, it's not designed for large amounts of data.

Comment: If the query returns only node names (only text return), check the option `Max rows` in `neo4j browser` settings. If you want to visualize a graph, you should look for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to get 30K names (or even all 100K) in a JSON document from the browser, the REST API might be able to do that without the browser running out of memory.

Try this from the browser:

```
:POST /db/data/cypher {"query" : "MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name LIMIT 30000"}
```

The browser will only display some of the results, but you can download the result in JSON format from the download icon on the top right side of the result panel.

To get *all* the names in a more compact JSON document, you can do this instead:

```
:POST /db/data/cypher {"query" : "MATCH (n:User) RETURN COLLECT(n.name)"}
```